# How to create makefile

Tags: c++, unix, compilation, makefile

I have to use make command on unix environment to compile the file.

I have

```
p4KyuCho.cpp

Stack.cpp

Stack.h
```

my make file is currently empty, can anyone help me

Comment: If you were going to compile this **without** make how would you do it?

Comment: Elementary tutorials on make are readily available on the Web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try something like this:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES= p4KyuCho.cpp Stack.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
*TAB* $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
*TAB* $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

From: http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

SPACING/TABBING IS VERY, I REPEAT, VERY IMPORTANT IN MAKEFILES. read up on that.